# Set the window title and icon of a PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am turning my website into a PWA, and went through the steps to make it downloadable, with its own icon on home screen.

However, I cannot find any documentation about how to set the window's title and icon, as it currently is chrome's icon and named `Application ...`. Is this possible, and if so, how can I achieve it?

---

The app's manifest:

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "short_name": "AppName",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "white",
  "theme_color": "black",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "../content/themes/AppName/images/fuzz.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }]
}
```

---

The app's window *(the window content is **removed for privacy**)* in Android:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Android distributions don't show the PWA name and icon in the app switcher, you can go to a known-good PWA to check if your distro is one of them.

Example manifest from [Airhorner](https://airhorner.com/):

```
{
  "name": "The Air Horner",
  "short_name": "Airhorner",
  "description": "The world's best airhorner, and it's free",
  "icons": [
      {
        "src": "/images/touch/android-launchericon-48-48.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "48x48"
      }, 

      {
        "src": "/images/touch/android-launchericon-72-72.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "72x72"
      }, 
      {
        "src": "/images/touch/android-launchericon-96-96.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "96x96"
      }, 
      {
        "src": "/images/touch/android-launchericon-144-144.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "144x144"
      }, 
      {
        "src": "/images/touch/android-launchericon-192-192.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
      }, 
      {
        "src": "/images/touch/android-launchericon-512-512.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "512x512"
      } 
      ],
  "start_url": "/?homescreen=1",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#2196F3",
  "theme_color": "#2196F3"
}
```

Result on the Pixel launcher:
[image]

Comment: I added my manifest to the question. I had already filled the "name" and "icons" attributes.

Comment: You can check in the Chrome devtools on your desktop (under the Application tab) if the manifest is detected correctly. If all the info checks out there, it might just be that your distribution of Android doesn't show the PWA icon and name in the app switcher.

Comment: Actually it's probably the latter, because I installed a couple of random PWA from the web, and all of them had the same issue. Or none of them knew how to do it, idk ...

Comment: In that case it's most likely your Android distro. The above example is hosted at https://emoji.debijl.xyz/, if you install that (File > Add to homescreen) and it still doesn't show up you can be pretty sure that it's your Android version/launcher.

Comment: Yep, still the same. Thanks for the debug help ! I guess you can edit your answer to wrap it all up, so I can accept it as solution.

Comment: Done, I used a slightly more generic PWA as an example (since my personal projects might not be online forever)